# Zero downtime deployment Nodejs application

Tags: node.js, deployment, uptime, downtime

I have a Nodejs application that included clustering for being uptime and domain for error handling.

Now for achieving zero downtime deployment, I have an instruction but I need help to convert this instruction to Nodejs code (I need an example for it please).

This is the instruction:

1. When master starts, give it a symlink to worker code.
2. After deploying new code, update symlink
3. Send a signal to master: fork new workers!
4. Mater tells old workers to shut down, forks new workers from new code.
5. Mater process never stop running

[Instruction source](https://www.slideshare.net/slideshow/embed_code/29391843) -> slide number 39

Comment: Alternative, you may want to check this https://www.chrismoos.com/2016/09/28/zero-downtime-deployments-kubernetes/ I've followed this setup in production and it works pretty well. Not exactly what you need, just sth to keep in mind.

Comment: Thanks but it was so far than my purpose!!

Answer (score 1):

For 100% uptime the road is more or less the same regardless of the language you are using:

- Store your session tokens in a database rather than in an in-memory array or something. This will allow users to stay logged-in after you swap versions.
- Run your server inside a Docker container
- Use a proxy to handle swapping containers when you need to run a new server version.

I wrote [easy-deploy](https://github.com/lazamar/easy-deploy) to handle exactly that, so that I wouldn't need to worry about setting up the proxy every time.

Deploy version 1

```
easy-deploy -p 80:80 -v some/path:other/path my-image:1
```

To deploy a new version just run the command with the updated tag name

```
easy-deploy -p 80:80 -v some/path:other/path my-image:2
```

The proxy is taken care of.
`my-image:1` will be replaced by `my-image:2` without letting any request drop.